# Google App Engine Eclipse Launch Local Host Multiple App Conflict?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I have two GAE projects created through pydev in eclipse 4.2 (windows 7) and the first one I had no issues running the localhost:8080 but when I created a second project, I duplicated the Run Configuration for local run adn just changed the project name to the new one. 
However- when I run that config the inital HelloWorld project shows up[ in my browser, I tried completely removing the first project, but then it just ocmplains it cant fint app.yaml in the old directory (because the old directory isnt where it was).

So clearly I'm missing some setting in the launch procedure where it sets the root path.
The run config is a PyDeb Google App Run, main module points to

```
C:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py
```

And the arguments are

```
${project_loc}\src
```

Everything else is on the default settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as pushing to Google (which works fine for both) for every little debug iteration is driving me a bit crazy.

Thanks!

*EDIT: Forgot to mention I have already tried to delete all runconfigs and remake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm just a bit silly. In eclipse, I wasn't properly turning off (not sure on the correct term there) the LocalHost for the first project before starting the second. To fix, I needed to go Into eclipses console window, and select "display selected console" and choose the project I wanted to stop and hit the stop all button. Then it runs fine.

Hope this helps someone in the future, that is as determined as me that "It can't be my fault".

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Run as : PyDev Google App Engine Run, to create a new runconfig?

Comment: Yes. My method to set up a new run config is: right clicking on my project folder->Run As->Run configuratiosn->Right Click on PyDev Google App Run->New.
Just tried deleting all run configs and removing/reinstalling GAE and creating a new runn config on the new project first and this did not help, local host still goes to old project.